# Can quantum entanglement contribute to entangled particle's decay?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Does a quantum entanglement have an influence on the entangled particle's decay?

Answer (score -1):

Considering that the neutrons in the nucleus are entangled quantum mechanically, the fact that the half-lives of the [beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay) depend on the isotope means that yes, entanglement affects decays.